# How to read external directory android?

Tags: android, image

I am saving an image like this

> ```
>     File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
>     File file = new File(path2, "new-photo-name.jpg");
>     outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
>                     intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
>                     cameraIntents.add(intent);
> ```

Basically, the image is saved in the pictures folder. My question is how can I read this image later new-photo-name.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you can get the file path by:

```
String imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

then next time make you can access the file by this path or make new file by this path

Comment: i get the following Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/new-photo-name.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: String path2 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/new-photo-name.jpg" this solved my issue